# Possible to use _.pluck on an object that contains arrays?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Say I have an object like the one below:

```
{
  mainId: 1,
  subArray1: [{count: 3, name: 'whatever'}, {count:5, name: 'something else'}],
  subArray2: [{count: 6, name: 'more stuff'}, {count:7, name: 'who cares'}]
}
```

Is there any way I can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)' [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) function to create an array of all counts for all arrays in the parent object?  I tried:

```
_.pluck(parentObject, 'count')
```

but this obviously doesn't work.  So far I have had to make a seperate call for each subArray:

```
_.pluck(parentObject.subArray1, 'count')
_.pluck(parentObject.subArray2, 'count')
```

And then concatenate the arrays.  Is there any way to use pluck on the parent object and get the values from all child arrays in one swoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you're looking to do with just `pluck`, but a combination of `map` and `pluck` should get you there:

```
_.map(parentObject, function(item) { return _.pluck(item, 'count'); }));
```

This will give you:

```
[[],[3,5],[6,7]]
```

If you wanted to discard the counts for the non-arrays, you could do that too:

```
_.compact(_.map(parentObject, function(item) {
  if (_.isArray(item)) { return _.pluck(item, 'count'); }
}));
```

This will return `null` for the non-arrays and then `compact` will remove the null values, to give you this:

```
[[3,5],[6,7]]
```

To flatten, just do:

```
_.flatten(_.compact(_.map(parentObject, function(item) {
  if (_.isArray(item)) { return _.pluck(item, 'count'); }
})));
```

which gives you:

```
[3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: `_.flatten` the result and you're there.

Comment: @Math Yeah, I couldn't tell if he wanted the flattened version or not. The question says he wants `an array of all counts for all arrays`, so I figured not. But I'll add that, thanks!

Comment: After the double pluck, OP says "_and concatenate the arrays_."

Answer (score 1):

You would have to loop over your original object, so something like this would work.
I don't think there is any way to avoid writing the loop in some form or another, i.e. map or forEach.

```
var resultArr = [];

_.each(parentObject, function(elem, index){
  resultArr = resultArr.concat(_.pluck(elem, 'count'););
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

```
var i = 0, subArray, counts = [];
while (subArray = ct['subArray' + (++i)]) {
    counts = counts.concat(subArray);
}
counts = _.pluck(counts, 'count');
```